# Resource or Restlet

Tags: restlet

I am using Restlet 2.2.1 and building Rest services. As you know, Router is used to attach either Restlet or Resource as target.

```
Router router = new Router( getContext() );

router.attach("/healthcheck1",HealthCheckResource.class );
router.attach("/healthcheck2", new HealthCheckRestlet() );
```

Then you can implement your logic in **handle()**

Wondering which is best one to use? I know Resource has a very definite life cycle (doInit, handle, release ...) and good place to implement one time logic like initialization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Attach a `ServerResource` subclass rather than a `Restlet` instance when feasible, for a couple of reasons:

- Resources are the natural way to structure RESTful APIs. When you use the `@Get`, `@Put`, etc. annotations on a resource class, you're effectively documenting that part of your RESTful API, and there are tools that can extract that information to create online documentation automatically. If you use a `Restlet` instance, its behavior in response to `GET`, `PUT`, etc. is not immediately apparent. Ironically, using a `Restlet` makes it easier to write APIs that are **not** RESTful.
- A separate instance of the resource class is created for **each** request, meaning that an instance is normally confined to a single thread, which simplifies reasoning about thread-safety. In constrast, the same `Restlet` instance will be used for all `handle(...)` calls, potentially leading to complicated thread-safety requirements.

Because each request gets its own resource instance, the resource methods might need to appeal to internal services that are passed via the application context or injected into the resource (see [this Restlet extension](https://restlet.com/open-source/documentation/user-guide/2.3/extensions/guice)).

Incidentally, your comment about "one time logic like initialization" might be a misunderstanding. The `doInit` method is called for each instantiated resource (i.e., once per request for that resource), **not** one time only.

Note that I'm recommending against directly subclassing `Restlet` as an end target for a resource URL, except maybe for trivial resources. Using **subclasses** of `Restlet` is a different matter: Attaching a `Filter` which **wraps** a resource is fine.